# Link icon changes vertical position in div depending on browser and OS

Tags: android, html, css

I'm trying to create a simple 3 line menu dropdown for mobile screens. I've got something that works, but it doesn't look consistent across devices. The icon's vertical positioning is changing depending on the OS and browser version. The icon should be centered vertically, but I'm seeing:

- Linux -desktop

  - Firefox - slightly low vertical centering.
  - Chrome - seems to be in the middle.
- Windows 8 -desktop

  - Firefox - seems to be in the middle.
  - IE 9-11 - seems to be in the middle.
- Android

  - Firefox - very low vertical centering.
  - Chrome - slightly low vertical centering.

Here is the sample HTML

```
<div id="nav">
  <div class="mobile-bars">
    <a href="#">&equiv;</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the sample CSS

```
#nav {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
.mobile-bars {
  background:#3e4041;
  height:50px;
  font-size:50px;
  line-height:1;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.mobile-bars a {
  color:white;
  position:absolute;
  display:block;
  padding:0 0.2em 0 0.2em;
  margin:0;
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

and here is the [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/91L29jwy/). Why won't the three line icon stay vertically centered?

Comment: I've decided to go with [this solution](http://jsfiddle.net/mha0oy17/) as referenced [here](http://timkadlec.com/2012/08/mobile-navigation-icons/). Still don't know why the font icon is changing position.

Comment: Ignore the previous... I've actually went with [this solution](http://jsfiddle.net/mha0oy17/1/). Its supported and looks the same across all browsers in the setup I'm trying to go with.

Answer (score 1):

Use `line-height: 50px;`, equals to the height of parent `(div.mobile-bars)` - [TRY DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/91L29jwy/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="nav">
  <div class="mobile-bars">
    <a href="#">&equiv;</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#nav {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
.mobile-bars {
  background:#3e4041;
  height:50px;
  font-size:50px;
  line-height:1;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.mobile-bars a {
  color:white;
  position:absolute;
  display:block;
  padding:0 0.2em 0 0.2em;
  margin:0;
  text-decoration:none;
  line-height: 50px;
}
```

**[EDITED]**

If you have `<meta charset="utf-8">` inside the `<head>` element and using the CSS property `line-height: 50px;` doesn't solve your problem then I would recommend you to use an `Image` instead of html unicode character, If you really worry about `Firefox on Linux and Android`, icon's vertical position.

Comment: Just checked it with my android device using firefox and in Linux using firefox. No change in behavior. the icon still isn't centered vertically.

Comment: @kzoo You have `<meta charset="utf-8">` inside the `<head>` element, RIGHT?